# What does the autoflush attribute in trace element do

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, trace

I have the following code in my web.config file:

```
<system.diagnostics>
    <trace autoflush="false" indentsize="4">
      <listeners>
        <add name="myListener" type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener" initializeData="TextWriterOutput.log" />
        <remove name="Default" />
      </listeners>
    </trace>
  </system.diagnostics>
```

and somewhere in my code behind:

```
System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine("From the trace");
```

After running the application, TextWriterOutput.log file was created successfully, but blank. However, after changing the autoflush attribute to true the trace wrote to TextWriterOutput.log.

I also noticed that I can make the trace write to TextWriteOutput.log by using

System.Diagnostics.Trace.Flush();

instead of modifying the autoflush attribute to true.

I read about it in 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.trace.flush(v=vs.110).aspx
but it didn't make sense to me. Why the trace cannot write immediately to the output file? Can anyone explain in simple words why?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `Flush` method forces the output to be written to the file. Setting the `autoflush` attribute to `true` causes Trace to always be written immediately to the file, instead of being buffered.

Comment: Still not making sense to me. Why is it buffered? why not sent it to the listener right off the bat?

Comment: @Bill file I/O is expensive; in general you don't want to write many small chunks of data to a file, but rather few large chunks. So the data is buffered until there's enough data to make the write more efficient. The drawback is that your log file doesn't immediately contain the data written to the trace, so the Flush method and the autoflush attribute let you override that behavior.

Comment: If using Trace temporarily, I find it useful to set it to True.